# "And please do be honest."?

Tags: grammar

Can you say this?

> And please do be honest.

I'm trying to tell somebody that I wish that they are honest with the reply that they are about to write to me.

Is the "do" part redundant?

Comment: The *do* is not redundant if you intend an [emphatic *do*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-emphatic-do-1690590).

Comment: Everyone speaks (and writes) differently. There are many ways to express the sentiment "Be honest". We have room, always, to choose how we do it. We can ask, ask politely, demand, insist -- as long as we're clear, grammatical, and in context, we can choose. Exercising this choice does not automatically mean that we're being redundant. I don't see your choice as a subject for debate. You seem to have wanted to request politely that someone be honest with you, and that is that. It's not redundant. It's clear and grammatical. It's nuanced. It's fine. Period.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are redundant, *but*...

Anecdotally, I have used the phrases 'Please do be honest' and 'Do be honest' as a polite way to invite criticism from someone who might have otherwise been reluctant to comment so frankly. For example:

> "What did you think about my paper? And please, do be honest, I don't mind if you thought it was bad."

Other phrases that aren't as grammatically redundant that can be used similarly are:
'You can be honest' or, with a frank tone, 'Be honest with me.'

Answer (score -1):

Both 'and', 'do' & 'please' are redundant. And you can simply say:

> Be honest.

However, they do modify the sense of the sentence and so are not redundant. For example, 'and' suggests this is in addition to some other preceding request. 'Please' is polite. 'Do' emphasises the request.

So it all depends upon what it is exactly you are trying to say.